# setting image source from url in window phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i am setting image source from URL , but it does not show image properly , 
code which i use in windows phone 8 is below , thanks in advance ..

```
 image1.Source =  new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://d3sdoylwcs36el.cloudfront.net/VEN-virtual-enterprise-network-business-opportunities-small-fish_id799929_size485.jpg",UriKind.Absolute));
```

result is 
[image]

Comment: this code works for me

Comment: hmm good but did not work for me ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i done it ,, call web service for image .. code is below ..

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += ImageOpenReadCompleted;
webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://d3sdoylwcs36el.cloudfront.net/VEN-virtual-enterprise-network-business-opportunities-small-fish_id799929_size485.jpg"));




private void ImageOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.Result);
        image1.Source = bmp;
    }
}
```

done it ... :)